# How to sync ignored files in GitHub

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have a repository with a `figs/` folder in it. The files in this folder are PNG images that are continuously being updated and I don't want to track these changes with Git so I added the folder to my `.gitignore` file. However, I do need these images to be in the GitHub repository.

I can not push the files because they are ignored, and if I try to add them manually to the GitHub repo, GitHub automatically makes a commit.

A solution similar to [this](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/issues/245) but without using git-ftp would be great.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: "don't want to track these changes with Git" and "need these images to be in the GitHub repository" are two conflicting requirements. Either you track them with Git and have them in GitHub, or you don't.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
# check the manual, read what it says about --force
man git 

# use --force to add the ignored directory files
git add --force figs/
```

Answer (score 0):

Git cannot do this.  Git is a version control system.  It therefore tracks versions of files, and it does that for all files under its control.

If you don't want to version these files, then they don't belong in Git.  This is especially true if they are build products, which do not belong in a version control system, and should be stored elsewhere, such as an artifact server or cloud bucket.

Comment: I have already considered your solution, but I thought maybe there was a smarter approach to the problem. Thank you anyway.